# Error when Importing Web3 in React: Module not found for './formats' and

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethereumjs, ganache, react

I'm encountering an issue while trying to import the Web3 library in a React project. The error message I'm receiving is:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './formats' in '/Users/kaustubhsharma/Desktop/learning web3/agri_product_price_monitor/node_modules/web3-validator/lib/esm'
Did you mean 'formats.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './formats' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e.g., a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
```

It seems that this error is related to the module resolution for the web3 package. I'm trying to use Web3 in a React application, and I've installed the package using npm. The error appears to be suggesting that the issue is related to the formats module, and it hints at changes in the module resolution due to strict EcmaScript Module handling.

I've checked my project's dependencies, and I'm using the latest versions of both React and Web3. Here's my import statement:
import Web3 from 'web3';

I've tried searching for solutions, but I haven't been able to find a clear answer to this problem. Can anyone provide insights into what might be causing this error and how I can resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.